# TYPO3: direct_mail - no plain text output

Tags: typo3-8.x

I'm using TYPO3 8.7.11 with fluid styled content and direct_mail 5.2.2.
As email format I've chosen text and html. I have included the two static templates in this order: 1) Direct Mail content bounderies, 2) Direct Mail plain text.

I have created my own fluid template for the HTML output and the output is perfect.

But no plain text email is created with the default template 'tx_directmail_pi1_plaintext.tmpl'. In preview I only see

```
Hello. This is default template for plain-text mail content ----------------- FOOTER: ---------------------- Unsubscribe link: https://example.com.test/?id=3&cmd=edit&aC=###SYS_AUTHCODE###&rU=###USER_uid###
```

If I create the two emails I get the warning

```
The plain text content does not contain any direct mail boundaries.
```

When I add the content bounderies manually the warning disappears but the markers are no filled with content.

So what can I do to get a plain text email besides the HTML email with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension [simplegrids](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/simplegrids/) provides a newsletter template with html and plain text output. You can use it in combination with direct_mail and TYPO3 8.7.x.