# Typo3 and DirectMail - Plaintext

Tags: typo3-8.x

I'm facing a problem with &type=99 - I created a page that's being sent as a Newsletter. I used FCE's from a provider extension to create the page. HTML works fine, But when I try to call the page in plaintext (&type=99), all I can see is  `Hello. This is default template for plain-text mail content [Unrendered Content Element...`

Any ideas how to solve this? (I'm using T3 8.7 and DM 5.3)

(using simplegrids, as mentioned here [TYPO3: direct_mail - no plain text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394518/typo3-direct-mail-no-plain-text-output) isn't an option)

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out it was pretty simple...

TS:

```
plaintext = PAGE
plaintext {

    typeNum = 99
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {

        templateName = Newsletter-99
        templateRootPaths {
          0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/
          10 = pathToMyExt/Resources/Private/Templates/Page
        }

        partialRootPaths {
          0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/
          10 = pathToMyExt/Resources/Private/Partials/
        }

        layoutRootPaths {
          0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/
          10 = pathToMyExt/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        }

        template = FILE
        template.file = pathToMyExt/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/Newsletter-99.html

    }

}
```

Then I created a new Template named «Newsletter-99.html» (s. above) with this content:

```
<f:format.stripTags><v:content.render column="0"/></f:format.stripTags>
```

This renders all fluid-templates and then strips all tags (which makes it basically plaintext).

That's it - after these changes I can call the page with &type=99 and I get a plaintext represenation of the Newsletter.